# For transporting 4000kg of cargo via Mi-17 helicopter for 54 km, how much maintenance cost per flight hour will be incurred?

Tags: military, helicopter, aircraft-maintenance, cost

In a disaster response case study, I am using Mi-17 helicopters for relief supplies transportation in a challenging logistics environment.

Regarding this, I want to check my estimates with the actual operational experience that community members may have..

Comment: I recommend you to contact a transport helicopter company or a SAR base. I suspect you need to discuss many items (and there is much logistic involved, so you may be very interested in it). This site is maybe not ideal (answers may not be connected to previous answers or questions, or answers may go in a direction you are not interested.

Comment: Ok dear got it!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maintenance cost is part man-hours, part hardware replacement. The first part depends on who's doing the maintenance, the second on how much flight hours the helicopter gets per year, since parts have both flight hour based and year-based replacement requirements.

[This discussion](https://www.pprune.org/rotorheads/186762-why-not-operating-russian-helicopter-4.html) lists Mi-8 rates being between `$1,050` and `$4,500/hr` in '05. Fuel burn is 650-900 liters per hour - use 750 for cost estimates, 900 for flight planning. The Mi-17 is basically an upgraded Mi-8. The costs have increased since, due to higher wages and the exhaustion of spares from military-surplus machines.

For study purposes, you could optimistically estimate it at `$2,500`+fuel for CIS and China, about `$3,000` for Asia, Africa, South America and East Europe, about `$5,000` for the EU, and `$6,000+` for North America and Australia. Add fuel. The difference is due to different availability of maintenance expertise and parts.

These are peacetime numbers. The costs are higher at the moment, due to high demand + trade disruptions. They will probably stay at about 1.5x for neutral/RU-aligned and further higher for US-aligned countries until the things boil over. They might not come down quite to the old levels, so I'd give it some risk adjustment to be safe.

Comment: for Asia, is it $3000 per flight hours?

Comment: I would estimate it at that, in the context of an academic study (long-term). Short-term, you would need to check with a local company. It's more expensive than it used to be, but still very competitive.

Comment: got it, long term value will be better

Comment: $3k is long-term. Right now it's more, the wait time for spares is longer.